# Extracting method arguments from a string in c#

Tags: c#, string, data-extraction

I have a simple file reader which reads through a number of .cs files searching for a specific method which has one parameter. If that method exists, then I want to scrape only the name of the parameter. I was thinking to do a string.Compare(), but then i don't know how to get to the index of the string where the argument starts.

```
void NameOfTheMethod(string name)
{}
```

In this example i want only to scrape out the 'name'.

EDIT: The parameter could also be a `const string` in some cases. Anyway to bypass that?

Comment: sounds like a job for Regex

Comment: The devil is in the details.  If you want a bullet-proof solution, then you need a C# parser.  If not, then you need to be more explicit about the assumptions you are making to simplify the problem.

Comment: Here is a contrived example: `Console.WriteLine("This will trick you: void NameOfTheMethod(string name) is part of a literal string.");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Regex. Something like

`NameOfTheMethod\(.*? (.*?)\)\s*?{`

edit:
Testing on your example, this will capture `name` only (and regardless of whether it's a string, int, object or whatever), not `string name`

edit2:

Complete example:

```
//using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
String input = "void NameOfTheMethod(string name)" + Environment.NewLine + "{}";
Regex matcher = new Regex(@"NameOfTheMethod\(.*? (.*?)\)\s*?{");
Match match = matcher.Match(input);

if (match.Success)
    Console.WriteLine("Success! Found parameter name: " + match.Result("$1"));
else
    Console.WriteLine("Could not find anything.");
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I'm fairly new with regular expressions. Can you just tell me how to would that be used in a piece of code? Maybe just a line or two of code. Which method is used to find that exact piece of a string?

Comment: @jonjohnson Regex is a big topic, but I added a working example which should get you going.

Comment: Hey Thanks. But I am not explicitly searching for 'name', because it could be anything. I'm looking for the variable name after the 'string' or 'const string' keyword. But thanks for the example

Comment: @jonjohnson yes you could input `"void NameOfTheMethod(string whatever)" + Environment.NewLine + "{}"` and the result would be `whatever`

Comment: yes, but i don't know what's gonna be. i'm searching for any kind of name after the string keyword

Comment: @jonjohnson maybe we're misunderstanding. You can use the same regex I provided on any input and it would return any word after the string keyword.

Answer (score 1):

By providing that you retrieve the codes by line you would get this :

```
void NameOfTheMethod(string name)
```

in a varibale named cdLine(for example)

Try using these lines of code

```
//Get Index of the opening parentheses
int prIndex = cdLine.IndexOf("("); // 20

//Cut the parameter code part
string pmtrString = cdLine.Substring(prIndex + 1); 
pmtrString = pmtrString.Remove(pmtrString.Length - 1);//"string name"//"string name"

//Use this line to check for number of parameters
string[] Parameters = pmtrString.Split(',');

// If it is 1 parameter only like in your example
string[] ParameterParts = pmtrString.Split(' ');// "string", "name"
string ParameterName = ParameterParts[ParameterParts.Length - 1];// "name"

// The ParameterName is the variable containing the Parameter name
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I think this will help you get the parameter name regardless of the number of keywords before it even if its out sting name it will return name. Just for the record There is a line extra in my last edit.

Answer (score 0):

this regex:

```
(?<=NameOfTheMethod\().+(?=\))
```

will capture `string name` if preceeded by `NameOfTheMethod(` and followed by `)`